# How to properly structure a ROS package?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, catkin, build, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My ROS package is beginning to get complicated with multiple folders for various aspects of functionality. However, I am unsure whether I have structured the package correctly. I am unsure whether my `urdf` and `config` folders should be placed outside of `src` and whether the nodes defined in Python scripts should be organised into a sub-folder (`scripts`) within `src`.

Here's what I have so far:

```
catkin_ws/src/my_package
│
├── cmake-build-debug
│   └── *LOTS OF SUB-FOLDERS & FILES*
├── include
│   └── my_package
│       └── *EMPTY*
├── venv
│   └── *LOTS OF SUB-FOLDERS & FILES*
├── launch
│   ├── all_nodes.launch
│   └── robot_simulation.launch
├── src
│   ├── config
│   │   ├── config_a.lua
│   │   └── config_b.rviz
│   ├── scripts
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── node_a.py
│   │   ├── node_b.py
│   │   ├── node_c.py
│   │   ├── node_d.py
│   │   ├── node_e.sh
│   │   └── node_f.sh
│   ├── urdf
│   │   ├── robot.urdf.xacro
│   │   ├── robot_plugins.gazebo
│   │   ├── mounts
│   │   │   ├── mount_a.urdf.xacro
│   │   │   ├── mount_b.urdf.xacro
│   │   │   └── mount_c.urdf.xacro
│   │   └── sensors.urdf.xacro
│   ├── gui
│   │   ├── index.html
│   │   └── main.js
│   └── worlds
│       └── area.world
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── package.xml
├── README.md
└── requirements.txt
```

Does this look right?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/364674/how-to-properly-structure-a-ros-package?/) by [Py](https://answers.ros.org/users/48264/py/) on ROS Answers with karma: 501 on 2020-11-03

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, I would not layout things as you have. Particularly `src` should be reserved for source code only (ie: Python, C++, etc).

No configuration files, no URDF nor Xacro, no Gazebo worlds, etc.

> My ROS package is beginning to get complicated with multiple folders for various aspects of functionality.

As a high-level comment: try to separate things a bit. You seem to treat `my_package` as a *mini workspace* almost. It's not.

Why not create a `my_package_gui`, `my_package_gazebo` and `my_package_description` package? Packages are almost free, so separate things as much as possible. Decrease coupling, separate concerns and delegate responsibilities.

---

There are various Q&As on ROS Answers about recommended package layout.

The ROS wiki also has a few pages which go into this, most notable [wiki/Packages](http://wiki.ros.org/Packages). It doesn't prescribe a particular layout, but does give some examples of *common folders* and where they are expected to be relative to a package's root.

An often referenced 3rd party resource on the topic of best practices is [leggedrobotics/ros_best_practices](https://github.com/leggedrobotics/ros_best_practices/wiki). The section [File/Folder Structure for Packages](https://github.com/leggedrobotics/ros_best_practices/wiki#filefolder-structure-for-packages) shows an often used example.

One thing to keep in mind: this structure is mostly *for humans*, as `roslaunch` and `rosrun` fi don't care where you've placed your binaries / executable scripts. They'll crawl the complete package and its sub directories. There are certainly things which must be in a certain location (such as the manifest and build script), but the rest is not important.

And an observation:

> ```
> catkin_ws/src/my_package
> ```

```
│
...
├── venv
...
```

Personally I would not place a Python `venv` inside the `src` space of a Catkin workspace, but you may have good reason to do so. You may want to look at tools such as [catkin_virtualenv](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin_virtualenv) to manage this instead.

---

Edit: and I just noticed this:

> ```
> catkin_ws/src/my_package
> ```

```
│
├── cmake-build-debug
..
```

What is `cmake-build-debug`? Are you doing in-source builds with `cmake` directly?

I would expect build artefacts to only exist in the `build` space of your Catkin workspace.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-11-03**:
Finally: as these are mostly conventions for humans, they tend to be subjective (ie: linked to preferences of whoever wrote them). Ask 100 developers this same question and you'll get a lot of different answers.

**Comment by [Py](https://answers.ros.org/users/48264/py/) on 2020-11-04**:
Fantastic! This has helped me re-structure. Thanks for the guidance. It turns out that the `cmake-build-debug` folder had been put in `src` by my IDE `CLion`, which was just incorrectly configured. The only thing I'm struggling with now is the Python `venv` folder. I like the idea of all this being handled using `catkin_virtualenv` but I can't seem to get it working. I usually create a virtual environment through the `CLion` GUI. If I just located the environment somewhere else would that be better? If so, where would you recommend?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-11-06**:\

> I like the idea of all this being handled using catkin_virtualenv but I can't seem to get it working

I would suggest you post a new question about the `catkin_virtualenv` problem.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-10-20**:
For now this seems like it has answered your (initial) question, so please mark the question as answered by ticking the checkmark to the left of the answer.